# If statements not working with char array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I have to write this program where when the user enters a word, it changes it to the plural version of it. I have three rules.

1. if it ends in a ‘y’, we change it to ‘ies’
2. if it ends in “sh” or “ch”, we add “es” to the end
3. Else, We add a ‘s’ at the end

I have this function named `WhichRule( char word[], char plural [])`, I am supposed to write if statements so I can see which rule to apply, the function `WhichRule` will call `RuleOne( char word[], char plural [])`, `RuleTwo( char word[], char plural [])`, and `RuleThree( char word[], char plural [])`.

I am having trouble writing my if statements, the code im going to copy is two different ways in which I’ve tried to write my if statements, but none have worked. I would appreciate any help.

```
void WhichRule(char word[], char plural[])
{
    int len = strlen(word);

    if (word[len - 1] = 'y')
    {
        ApplyRuleOne(plural, word);
        printf("this");
    }
    else if (word[len - 2, len - 1] = 'c', 'h')
    {
        ApplyRuleTwo(plural, word);
        printf("is");
    }
    else if (word[len - 2] == 's' && word[len - 1] == 'h')
    {
        ApplyRuleTwo(plural, word);
        printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
       ApplyRuleThree(plural, word);
       printf("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: `word[len - 1] == 'y'` equality not assignment  and `word[len - 2, len - 1] = 'c', 'h'` --> `word[len-2]=='c' && word[len-1]=='h'`.

Comment: `else if (word[len - 2, len - 1] = 'c', 'h')` - what on earth is this?

Comment: You have a comma operator in your `else-if`, and again assignment instead of checking equality.

Comment: And the expression `word[len - 2, len - 1] = 'c', 'h')` assigns an `'h'` to `word[len-1]`.... you have a couple [comma operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do) in that expresion there

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Here is a common mistake of confusing '=' with '=='.
'=' is assignment operator ans is used to assign value to a variable
So

```
if (word[len - 1] = 'y')
```

This will *assign* the value 'y' to variable word[len-i]

**Solution**

To *compare* the values, use '==' like

```
if (word[len - 1] == 'y')
```

**Code**

```
void WhichRule(char word[], char plural[])
{
    int len = strlen(word);

    if (word[len - 1] == 'y')
    {
        ApplyRuleOne(plural, word);
        printf("this");
    }
    else if (word[len - 2] == 'c' && word[len - 1] == 'h')
    {
        ApplyRuleTwo(plural, word);
        printf("is");
    }
    else if (word[len - 2] == 's' && word[len - 1] == 'h')
    {
        ApplyRuleTwo(plural, word);
        printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
       ApplyRuleThree(plural, word);
       printf("test");
    }
}
```

[P.S : Also there was problem with the line that checks for last characters 'ch'.]

Comment: A residual problem is that if you pass `"a"` as the word, the code tries to access the character before the beginning of the word, which is undefined behaviour.